# Header is no longer in the dead center of the container

Tags: html, css

I have a header which is inside of a div. I want the header to be in the center of the div, but I need the text to be large. If I don't specify a font-size the header will be centered, but as soon as I enter in the vm for the size of the text it goes off center.

```
<div>

<h1 style="position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;font-size:20vw">
Header
</h1>

</div>
```

Comment: @SherinBinu That is not a typo. Essentially I have a div which is dynamic in size (depending on the screen size). I would like the font to always be 100% the height of this div.

Comment: Your text starts from the center. Its not centered. There is a difference

Comment: @user2924127 What size in vw indicate actually ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `transform` like

```
h1 {
    font-size: 20vw;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wudquLpd/

Answer (score 1):

Way you are making center, it uses the top left corner to be center

[image]

so thats why it never truly in the center of the div.

Suggestion to achieve center you need to be precise like your H1 should have width and height then you can do this

```
<div>
  <h1 style="position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    font-size: 10vw;
    background-color: #ff0000;
    margin-left: calc(-32vw/2);
    width: 32vw;
    height: 10vw;
    margin-top: calc(-10vw/2);">
    Header
  </h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the padding and margin to 0

```
<div>
  <h1 style="position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;font-size:20vw;margin:0;padding:0">
    Header
  </h1>
</div>
```

It makes the text starts from the center of the div, not centered though. But I guess, thats the way you wanted based on what you specified in the question

Comment: I need it to be centered, not start from the center. I have tried this, but it didn't work:  <h1 style="position:absolute;top:50%;width:100%;font-size:20vw;margin:0;padding:0;align:center">

Comment: The comment I wrote here was incorrect and can be deleted

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, you dont need to calculate anything with this method.

```
<div><h1 style="width:90%;margin:auto;font-size:20vw;text-align:center">Header</h1></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div>
<h1 style="font-size:20vw;text-align:center">    Header    </h1>
</div>
```

This might be also one of the solution to your problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
  <div style="position: absolute; top:50%; left: 50%;">
     <h1 style="position: relative; left: -50%; font-size:10vw;">
        Header
     </h1>
  </div>
 </body>
```